# Graphs without short cycles and with linear number of edges

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Let $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a non-decreasing function and let $X_f$ be the class of graphs where every $n$-vertex graph $G$ is $(C_3, C_4, \ldots, C_{f(n)})$-free, i.e. $G$ contains no cycles of length at most $f(n)$.

It is known that if $f$ is constant, then graphs in $X_f$ can have a superlinear number $n^{1+\epsilon(f)}$ of edges. On the other hand, if $f : n \mapsto n$, then $X_f$ is the class of forests, which have a linear number of edges.

I'm wondering if there is a transition from the superlinear to the linear regime.

For example, is there a known function $f^*$ such that

1. for any $g \in o(f^*)$, the class $X_g$ has $n$-vertex graphs with a superlinear number ($\omega(n)$) of edges;
2. for any $g \in \omega(f^*)$, the graphs in $X_g$ have a linear number of edges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Threshold is $\log n$.

1. If the graph has at least, say, $2n$ edges, it has a cycle of length at most, say, $2\log_2 n$ (proof: remove vertices of degree at most 2 while it is possible. After each step, $|E|\geqslant 2|V|$ property is preserved. So, you get a graph with all degrees at least 3,and considering DFS from any vertex you find a cycle of above mentioned length.)
2. For any $C>0$, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that there exists a graph with $Cn$ edges and all cycles not shorter than $\varepsilon \log n$. (proof: take a random graph $G(n, 5C/n)$ and destroy all short cycles.)